# AWS Go SDK V2: assuming different roles concurrently

Tags: go, thread-safety, aws-sdk-go, aws-roles

I'm learning to write microservices in Go and I have created an API endpoint using Gin. My use case is that this endpoint receives an AWS role and then assumes it to access some AWS resource.
I found out that Gin handles each incoming reqeust in a different go routine and my concern is if this role assumption would work parallely.

I found the following example on how to assume a role on Stackoverflow:

```
stsClient := sts.NewFromConfig(cfg)
provider := stscreds.NewAssumeRoleProvider(stsClient, roleARN)
cfg.Credentials = aws.NewCredentialsCache(provider)
```

I'm currently loading `aws.Config` into a variable, `cfg`, at the start of the microservice in the `main` package and I could pass it to the service layer to share it. My questions are:

- Does every request need to load aws config? I'm concerned about the following line that will change the config credential for each request and leave it in the modified state which might cause issues if `cfg` is passed to API response logic.

```
cfg.Credentials = aws.NewCredentialsCache(provider)
```

- Is the role assumption operation thread safe?

Any guidance is appreciated.
TIA

Comment: It's hard to answer this without more context. What is `cfg`? What is its scope? Regardless of anything to do with AWS role assumption, if this is a variable shared between goroutines, you've created a race condition.

Comment: Hi @Adrian, regarding the variable, its not shared between go routines yet. That's why I was wondering if I should avoid using it in the API logic.
Regarding `cfg`, its aws [Config](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/config@v1.26.6#LoadDefaultConfig) loaded with the SDK's default external configurations. As for the scope, if I understand correctly, it can assume the input role and gets all the permissions from that role only.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the variable scope - your question says "might cause issues if it is a shared variable" and it *will* cause issues if it's a shared variable, specifically race conditions.

Comment: Ah ok, the variable is public, but currently its not being used in API response logic, or in any go routine.

Comment: Go doesn't have public variables, the closest it has is exported package variables, and `cfg` isn't an exported name. No code runs outside of goroutines (even `main` runs in a goroutine). Can you maybe revise the question to show where this variable is defined, where it is being written to, and where it is being read from?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, I meant `cfg` is defined in the `main` package, and its not being used outside the `main` goroutine. One option I have is to pass this config, `cfg` to the API response logic and use it there. However, as you mentioned, this would create race condition. So I'm looking for best practices for such use cases. I'll add this to the question too.

Comment: The Go SDKs from AWS typically have pretty good concurrency support.  https://aws.github.io/aws-sdk-go-v2/docs/making-requests/ explains the clients (eg `stsClient`) can be used in multiple goroutines concurrently.  If you share the sts client, that will obviate the question about sharing the config.  My guess is that a config could be safely shared across goroutines, but I didn't see it written anywhere

Comment: @erik258 yes, I had the exact same thought but I couldn't find any definite proof about the configs being thread safe either :(

Comment: Config is internally thread-safe, but once you have it in a shared variable that's being read and written by multiple code paths you have to worry about your own code being thread-safe.

Comment: @Adrian so instead of sharing the variable, if every go routine loads the config and creates the client using local variables we should be good right?